# Why is the condition $\mathbb E[X^2]< \infty, \mathbb E[Y^2]< \infty$ needed in the definition of the covariance?

Tags: probability-theory

In the definition of the covariance of two variables $X$ and $Y$, one can see the following condition mentioned:

> $$\mathbb E[X^2]< \infty,\text{ and }\mathbb E[Y^2]< \infty.$$

Why is this condition needed, and how does it guarantee the existence of $\mathbb E [(X-\mathbb E[X])(Y-\mathbb E[Y])]$?

Comment: How does it guarantee the existence? Please see the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I thought about it, but it seems that the proof of the inequality (http://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter6/6_2_4_cauchy_schwarz.php) itself relies on the fact that $\mathbb E(XY)$ eixists, does not it?

Comment: @SergeyZykov Note that $\mathbb{E}(|X \cdot Y|)$ always exists (it may be infinite). Applying the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, it follows that $\mathbb{E}(|X \cdot Y|) \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X^2)} \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(Y^2)}$ is finite. Consequently, $\mathbb{E}(X Y)$ exists and the claim follws from the inequality $$\mathbb{E}(XY) \leq \mathbb{E}(|XY|)$$

Comment: Also note that the covariance can be written as $cov(X,Y)=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$.

Comment: @saz I thought the CS inequality states that  $\left| \mathbb{E}(X \cdot Y) \right| \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X^2)} \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(Y^2)}$ not $\mathbb{E}(|X \cdot Y|) \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X^2)} \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(Y^2)}$. The proof of the inequality operates with $\mathbb E[XY]$ as with a number, so the proof assumes that $\mathbb E[XY]$ which is a limit of partial sums of the series converges, and I do not see why $\mathbb E[XY]$ can not be divergent (not even divergent to $\pm \infty$).

Comment: @SergeyZykov If you choose $\tilde{X} := |X|$ and $\tilde{Y} := |Y|$, then the inequality $$|\mathbb{E}(\tilde{X} \cdot \tilde{Y})| \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(\tilde{X}^2)} \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(\tilde{Y}^2)}$$ yields $$\mathbb{E}(|X Y|) \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X^2)} \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(Y^2)}.$$

Comment: @saz all right, that actually helps a lot. So the whole proof can be ran through not with $X$ and $Y$, but with $\left| X \right|$ and $\left| Y \right|$, to get $|\mathbb{E}(X Y)| \le \mathbb{E}(|X Y|) \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X^2)} \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(Y^2)}$. But still inside the proof I operate with $\mathbb{E}(|X Y|)$ as with a number, and the proof becomes kind of circular, I operate with $\mathbb{E}(|X Y|)$ as if it was a number and not $\infty$ within the proof and at the end of the proof I conclude that is indeed a number and not $\infty$.

Comment: @SergeyZykov That's correct. In this case, you should add more details of the proof to your question. (The proof I know does no such thing...)